# ERROR: net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1::dantrell-gnome failed (compile phase)

Tags: gnome, gentoo

I've got error while compiling GNOME 3.24 on Gentoo:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wsign-compare -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-parameter -march=native -O2 -pipe  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed -o mission-control-5 mc-server.o -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -ltelepathy-glib -ldbus-glib-1 -ldbus-1 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 ../src/libmcd-convenience.la ../mission-control-plugins/libmission-control-plugins.la 
libtool: link: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wsign-compare -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-parameter -march=native -O2 -pipe -Wl,-O1 -o .libs/mission-control-5 mc-server.o -pthread  -Wl,--as-needed ../src/.libs/libmcd-convenience.a /var/tmp/portage/net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1/work/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3/mission-control-plugins/.libs/libmission-control-plugins.so -lupower-glib ../mission-control-plugins/.libs/libmission-control-plugins.so -ltelepathy-glib -ldbus-glib-1 -ldbus-1 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -pthread
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lupower-glib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:504: mission-control-5] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1/work/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3/server'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:545: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1/work/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3'
make: *** [Makefile:451: all] Error 2
 * ERROR: net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1::dantrell-gnome failed (compile phase):
 *   emake failed
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1::dantrell-gnome'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1::dantrell-gnome'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1/work/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1/work/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3'

>>> Failed to emerge net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1, Log file:

>>>  '/var/tmp/portage/net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1/temp/build.log'
*** Resuming merge...

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!

 * Messages for package net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1:

 * ERROR: net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1::dantrell-gnome failed (compile phase):
 *   emake failed
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1::dantrell-gnome'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1::dantrell-gnome'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1/work/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1/work/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3'
 * One or more packages are either masked or have missing dependencies:
 * 
 *   net-im/telepathy-mission-control pulled in by:
 *     (net-libs/telepathy-glib-0.24.1:0/0::dantrell-gnome, installed)
 * 
 * The resume list contains packages that are either masked or have
 * unsatisfied dependencies. Please restart/continue the operation
 * manually, or use --skipfirst to skip the first package in the list and
 * any other packages that may be masked or have missing dependencies.
 * 
 * The following package has failed to build, install, or execute postinst:
 * 
 *  (net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1:0/0::dantrell-gnome, ebuild scheduled for merge), Log file:
 *   '/var/tmp/portage/net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1/temp/build.log'
 *
```

Build log: https://paste.pound-python.org/show/...F5v3n3XCHcaOq/
The result of emerge --info '=net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1::dantrell-gnome': https://paste.pound-python.org/show/...Gcmtq9KwNlx16/
The result of emerge -pqv '=net-im/telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3-r1::dantrell-gnome': https://paste.pound-python.org/show/...hYlERUUTerLZk/

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the first line says:

```
 cannot find -lupower-glib
```

So you need to to have `libupower-glib` (or something llike that) available (i.e. installed) on your system to emerge `telepathy-mission-control`.

Seems like the build dependencies are not completely declared on the `telepathy-mission-control` package. You should problably report that as a bug.